# How to redirect all request on port 80 to a docker and then pass it to my web server?

Tags: apache, docker, web-application-firewall

How can I put a docker between the web requests and my web server (in order to analyse and block requests)? I found morbz/docker-web-redirect docker, but it seems that it is not enough for this task.

Comment: What have you already tried?  Why would Docker necessarily be involved?

Comment: @DavidMaze because by using docker, the setup process would be easier for my customers (instead of installing a Linux daemon to block requests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using nginx as reverse proxy, or better haproxy:

https://hub.docker.com/_/haproxy/

You have to configure haproxy container to listen to port 80 on the host, then direct traffic to your proxied web server.

Haproxy ACLS might be of your interest: [How to route traffic (reverse Proxy) with HAProxy based on request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259843/how-to-route-traffic-reverse-proxy-with-haproxy-based-on-request-body)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can I block requests on a docker? (block them in order to protect the web server outside of the docker)

Comment: Yes you can. That's one of the usual tasks of a reverse proxy. It just depends on what's the criteria for blocking.

Comment: Thank you very much